# Proper return type for a c++ function?

Tags: c++

What type identifier should this function have? auto and 'long long'(teacher recommendations) give compiler errors. I also tried chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point which also gave an error.

```
auto ComputeDuration(chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start_time, chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end_time) {
     return end_time - start_time;
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured but chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point in the place of long long also gave a compiler error.

Comment: Which c++ standard are you compiling with?

Comment: I see. I was using c++11. auto requires c++14 or higher.

Comment: if you get errors you should include them in the question

Comment: are you stuck with c++11? Have you tried changing "time_point" to "duration" in the return type?

Comment: When compiler 'gives you errors*, the first step is to read the error message.

Comment: If you're using visual studio, the "Error" window shows error _summaries_.  Open the "Output" window to view the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is just syntactic sugar for "compiler please deduce this type for me". It changes *nothing* about what the *actual* type is.

Whether you write out the actual type the function returns or use `auto` (*if* it can be deduced) changes *nothing*. The function still returns the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one `high_resolution_clock::time_point` from another will be done using this operator:

```
template<class Clock, class Duration1, class Duration2>
constexpr std::common_type_t<Duration1, Duration2>
    operator-( const time_point<Clock, Duration1>& end_time,
               const time_point<Clock, Duration2>& start_time);
```

It returns the [common type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) (`std::common_type_t<Duration1, Duration2>`) of the two `time_point`'s `Duration` template parameter:

```
template<
    class Clock,
    class Duration = typename Clock::duration
> class time_point;
```

Since your function takes two arguments of the same `time_point` type, the returned type will be:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration
```

---

If you'd like to use `auto` in C++11 mode, you need to supply a trailing return type:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

// I suggest taking the arguments by const& instead of by value
auto ComputeDuration(
    const high_resolution_clock::time_point& start_time,
    const high_resolution_clock::time_point& end_time) -> decltype(end_time-start_time)
{
     return end_time - start_time;
}
```

The type of the returned value will be the same: `high_resolution_clock::duration`

Comment: @MooingDuck I tried to make it clearer. I hope it didn't have the opposite effect.

Comment: That's much more descriptive. Good job

Comment: @MooingDuck Many thanks! (and thanks to Remy for helping out too :-) )